# Image slider with complex navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a slider with some complex navigation features.

This is the code that doesn't seem to work :

```
$('#bulletLooper').on('shown', function (e) {
 $('.looper-nav > li', this)
   .removeClass('active')
   .eq(e.relatedIndex)
   .addClass('active');
});
```

Complete example on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Laurent514/N3Wgp/17/

What I need to do here is set an active class on the color indicator box and on the color picker box associated with the active slide. The JS script works fine on the navigation thumbnails but it seems that adding active class to multiple elements is not supported or maybe I am doing this the wrong way. The JS script that is used to set the active class is located at the end of the JS fiddle JS window.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Laurent

Comment: How do you mean: multiple elements? The `.eq` picks out one single element, so `.addClass` is only called on one of them, right?

Comment: Actually I was expecting that if I use a class name I could pick every elements that has the same class name, in this case .looper-nav > li which is repeated in the page. Any workaround?

Comment: Yes, you can, and that works. But why are you using `.eq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/N3Wgp/18/

Changes made:

First - since the same selector can be used for all 3 lists easily, I stopped using .eq and used .filter with nth-child selector - this allowed selecting the li elements from all 3 .looper-nav lists to give them the active class, and also stopped scoping the selector to the .looper.slide object -- all done by some minor changes to the JS you had at the bottom.

```
$('#bulletLooper').on('shown', function (e) {
    $('.looper-nav > li')
        .removeClass('active')
        .filter(':nth-child('+(e.relatedIndex+1)+')')
        .addClass('active');
});
```

Second - A few minor CSS rules to apply the display change for the colour indicator now it's got the active class available. Just add this to the end of your CSS.

```
.color-indicator .looper-nav > li {
    display: none;
}
.color-indicator .looper-nav > li.active {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: .filter with nth-child selector! Very useful, saved me a lot of time!